# How to send a discord.js random embed?

Tags: random, discord.js, bots, embed

I'm looking for a code that would let me send an random embed that I created when someone types a command. For the moment with the code that I have, all embeds are being sent but I want the bot to only send a random one, not all 4. Is this possible ?

```
module.exports = class PizzaTest extends BaseCommand {
  constructor() {
    super('pizzatest', 'fun', []);
  }

  async run(client, message, args) {
      const capreseEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle('• Attention, pizza en livraison!  ')
      .setDescription(`<@${message.author.id}>, il semblerait que ta commande soit prête. Tu viens de recevoir une magnique pizza **Caprese** ! \n\n *Les ingrédients sont: Mozarella, Olives, Tomates Séchées & Basilic.*`)
      .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/McSXASC.png')
      .setFooter(message.author.username, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
      .setTimestamp()
      .setColor("#baff58");

      const reineEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle('• Attention, pizza en livraison!  ')
      .setDescription(`<@${message.author.id}>, il semblerait que ta commande soit prête. Tu viens de recevoir une magnique pizza **Reine** ! \n\n *Les ingrédients sont: Mozarella, Jambon, Champignons & Basilic.*`)
      .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/AKStODY.png')
      .setFooter(message.author.username, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
      .setTimestamp()
      .setColor("#baff58");

      const vegeEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle('• Attention, pizza en livraison!  ')
      .setDescription(`<@${message.author.id}>, il semblerait que ta commande soit prête. Tu viens de recevoir une magnique pizza **Végétarienne** ! \n\n *Les ingrédients sont: Mozarella, Olives, Poivrons, Champignons & Basilic.*`)
      .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/U0qrSk9.png')
      .setFooter(message.author.username, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
      .setTimestamp()
      .setColor("#baff58");

      const andalouseEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle('• Attention, pizza en livraison!  ')
      .setDescription(`<@${message.author.id}>, il semblerait que ta commande soit prête. Tu viens de recevoir une magnique pizza **Andalouse** ! \n\n *Les ingrédients sont: Mozarella, Poivrons, Boulette de Boeuf & Sauce Andalouse.*`)
      .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/dvgkC4K.png')
      .setFooter(message.author.username, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
      .setTimestamp()
      .setColor("#baff58");


  message.channel.send(capreseEmbed).catch(err => console.log(err));
  message.channel.send(reineEmbed).catch(err => console.log(err));
  message.channel.send(vegeEmbed).catch(err => console.log(err));
  message.channel.send(andalouseEmbed).catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
}
```

I know that I can use something like `.setDescription(description)` with all of them stated at the beginning but I need the description and thumbnail to match so that wouldn't work I guess ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible and very simple to do:

```js
      const capreseEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle('• Attention, pizza en livraison!  ')
      .setDescription(`<@${message.author.id}>, il semblerait que ta commande soit prête. Tu viens de recevoir une magnique pizza **Caprese** ! \n\n *Les ingrédients sont: Mozarella, Olives, Tomates Séchées & Basilic.*`)
      .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/McSXASC.png')
      .setFooter(message.author.username, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
      .setTimestamp()
      .setColor("#baff58")

      const reineEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle('• Attention, pizza en livraison!  ')
      .setDescription(`<@${message.author.id}>, il semblerait que ta commande soit prête. Tu viens de recevoir une magnique pizza **Reine** ! \n\n *Les ingrédients sont: Mozarella, Jambon, Champignons & Basilic.*`)
      .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/AKStODY.png')
      .setFooter(message.author.username, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
      .setTimestamp()
      .setColor("#baff58")

      const vegeEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle('• Attention, pizza en livraison!  ')
      .setDescription(`<@${message.author.id}>, il semblerait que ta commande soit prête. Tu viens de recevoir une magnique pizza **Végétarienne** ! \n\n *Les ingrédients sont: Mozarella, Olives, Poivrons, Champignons & Basilic.*`)
      .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/U0qrSk9.png')
      .setFooter(message.author.username, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
      .setTimestamp()
      .setColor("#baff58")

      const andalouseEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle('• Attention, pizza en livraison!  ')
      .setDescription(`<@${message.author.id}>, il semblerait que ta commande soit prête. Tu viens de recevoir une magnique pizza **Andalouse** ! \n\n *Les ingrédients sont: Mozarella, Poivrons, Boulette de Boeuf & Sauce Andalouse.*`)
      .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/dvgkC4K.png')
      .setFooter(message.author.username, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
      .setTimestamp()
      .setColor("#baff58")

      var embedArr = [capreseEmbed, reineEmbed, vegeEmbed, andalouseEmbed];
      let randomEmbed = embedArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * embedArr.length)];
      message.channel.send(randomEmbed);
```

At first we define all embeds, like you already did. Then we store them in an array. From that array we want to get a value from a random index. That is done in `randomEmbed`. Then we send the random embed into the channel.

Comment: That was more than easy ! I didn't know I could store embeds in an array like that, super cool. Thank you so much for your quick answer !

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easy way:

```
    const Thumbnail = [
     'https://i.imgur.com/McSXASC.png',
     'https://i.imgur.com/AKStODY.png',
     'https://i.imgur.com/U0qrSk9.png',
     'https://i.imgur.com/dvgkC4K.png',
    ]

   const Description = [
     ', il semblerait que ta commande soit prête. Tu viens de recevoir une magnique pizza **Caprese** ! \n\n *Les ingrédients sont: Mozarella, Olives, Tomates Séchées & Basilic.*`',
     ', il semblerait que ta commande soit prête. Tu viens de recevoir une magnique pizza **Végétarienne** ! \n\n *Les ingrédients sont: Mozarella, Olives, Poivrons, Champignons & Basilic.*`',
     ', il semblerait que ta commande soit prête. Tu viens de recevoir une magnique pizza **Végétarienne** ! \n\n *Les ingrédients sont: Mozarella, Olives, Poivrons, Champignons & Basilic.*`',
     ', il semblerait que ta commande soit prête. Tu viens de recevoir une magnique pizza **Andalouse** ! \n\n *Les ingrédients sont: Mozarella, Poivrons, Boulette de Boeuf & Sauce Andalouse.*`', 
   ]

    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * Thumbnail.length)

    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
     .setTitle('• Attention, pizza en livraison!  ')
     .setDescription( '`' + message.author.username + Description[random])
     .setThumbnail(Thumbnail[random])
     .setFooter(message.author.username, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
     .setTimestamp()
     .setColor("#baff58")

message.channel.send(embed)
```